# Angular 2 Check if email exists

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular-forms

I'm struggling to make a method that checks if an email address exists in my DB.
If it does, I should get 1 as response and 0 if it doesn't.
Here's my form HTML :

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="addUser(utilisateur)" [formGroup]="formUtilisateur">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email*:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse Email" formControlName="email">
          </div>
        <div class="error text-center alert alert-danger" *ngIf="formUtilisateur.get('email').hasError('incorrectEmailFormat') && formUtilisateur.get('email').touched">
          Format Email incorrect.
        </div>
        <div class="error text-center alert alert-danger" *ngIf="formUtilisateur.get('email').hasError('emailExistant') && formUtilisateur.get('email').touched">
          Already taken
        </div>
        <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info bnt-lg col-md-12" [disabled]="formUtilisateur.invalid">Sign up</button>
    </form>
```

Now my signup.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Utilisateur } from "../../models/utilisateur";

@Injectable()
export class SignupService {

  urlCheckEmail: string = 'http://localhost:8080/signup/checkEmail';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  checkEmail(email:string) {
    return this.http.post(this.urlCheckEmail, email)
      .map((res: Response) =>{return res.json().status});
  }
}
```

Now my component that uses the service signup.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Utilisateur } from "../../models/utilisateur";
import { SignupService } from "../../services/signup/signup.service";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  formUtilisateur: FormGroup;
  utilisateur: Utilisateur;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formUtilisateur = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.emailExisteValidation])]
    });
  }

  constructor(private signupService: SignupService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  emailExisteValidation() {
    this.signupService.checkEmail(this.formUtilisateur.controls['email'].value).subscribe(data => {
if(data != 0)
      return { "emailExistant": true };
    })
    return null;
  }
}
```

While in the browser console, I see this as error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'signupService' of undefined
>       at
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/components/signup/signup.component.ts.SignupComponent.emailExisteValidation
>   (signup.component.ts:54)    ...

Line 54 is : `this.signupService.checkEmail(this.formUtilisateur.controls['email'].value).subscribe(data => {`

I don't know if it's the best way to check if an email address exists but that's what I've tried so far and it doesn't work.

For example, for *test@test.com* I should get **1** as response as it's already stored in my DB. [Postman checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTJWe.jpg)

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Hey, I think that you are seeing that error because the template gets compiled before your component properties get instantiated.

Comment: Look into using the following:
Inject & forwardRef. 
This will inject the service and create it so you can use it as soon as possible.

constructor(
@Inject(forwardRef(() => signupService)) private signupService: SignupService).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @inoabrian. I declared `signupService: SignupService;` and tried `constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => SignupService)) signupService:SignupService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}` but it didn't work.

Comment: I still get the same error as in my initial post.

Answer (score -1):

Please add the SignupService in the providers in your module/component.

```
providers: [SignupService]
```

Also,

```
let control = this.formUtilisateur.get('email');
if (control.valid && control.dirty) {
    this.signupService.checkEmail(this.formUtilisateur.controls['email'].value).subscribe(data => {
        if(data != 0)
          return { "emailExistant": true };
        })
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It says me *"Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ [key: string]: Abst
ractControl; }' has no compatible call signatures."* for `let control = this.formUtilisateur.controls('email');`

Comment: Try to use this: let control = this.formUtilisateur.get('email');

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my last comment. I tried with " this.formUtilisateur.get('email');" but I still get the same error as in my initial post.

Comment: Can you add all files to plnkr and reproduce this error on plnkr?